# Woocommerce Checkout Field editor, Datepicker restrict array of dates and restrict the closest 5 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I think maybe i wasn´t to clear in my question.

I want to do two things with my jquery datepicker (in this case its a part of woocommerce custom checkout fields add on)

1: Disable the next 5 days in the calendar.
2: Disable certain days/periods like holidays, closed days etc.

I´ve been able to achive both of these individually with the following functions but they don´t work when I use them both. Then only #2 works.
Any good suggestions?

How can I combine these two functions I´ve found so far:

This one who restrict the closest 5 days.

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer' , 'woo_add_checkout_field_date_range_limit' );
function custom_adjust_datepicker_range () {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( e ) {
    if ( jQuery( '.checkout-date-picker' ).length ) {
        jQuery( '.checkout-date-picker' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', '+5' );
    }
});
</script>
<?php
    }
} // End custom_adjust_datepicker_range()
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_adjust_datepicker_range', 50 );
```

And this that block an array of dates (holidays etc...)

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_callback');
function wp_footer_callback(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
        var unavailableDates = ["21-11-2020", "22-11-2020", "23-11-2020"];
        function unavailable(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
            }
        }
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
<?php   
}
```

I tried to add the

```
jQuery( '.checkout-date-picker' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', '+5' );
```

in with the

```
jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
```

Did not work.

I appologize for the newbie question and I probably could have found the answer somewhere else too, but then again. This is always a good source to good guidance.

Comment: Hi try this way:
jQuery( '.checkout-date-picker' ).each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker(...);
});

Comment: @MiguelAngelMartinez Not sure what you suggest. Can you give me more info?